# Fetching the column data from different sheets and making it as row data in MainSheet

Tags: excel, vba

Following is the code to fetch the data from the last column of each sheet and display it in the sheet "MainSheet". Since the last column has merged cells this code also deletes the cells in between
This code displays the data as verical view in the MainSheet and I want to make it horizontal i.e data from the last column of each sheet should be fetched to the rows in the MainSheet and also the merged cells should be taken care of

```
Sub CopyLastColumns()
    Dim cnt As Integer, sht As Worksheet, mainsht As Worksheet, col As Integer, rw As Integer
    ActiveSheet.Name = "MainSheet"
    Set mainsht = Worksheets("MainSheet")

    cnt = 1
    For Each sht In Worksheets
        If sht.Name <> "MainSheet" Then
            sht.Columns(sht.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Copy
            mainsht.Columns(cnt).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            mainsht.Cells(150, cnt) = sht.Range("A2")
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next sht

    With mainsht
        For col = 1 To cnt
            For rw = .Cells(65536, col).End(xlUp).row To 1 Step -1
                If .Cells(rw, col) = "" Then
                    .Cells(rw, col).Delete Shift:=xlUp
                End If
            Next rw
        Next col
    End With
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code copies the last column from every sheet and pastes them as rows in the `MainSheet` keeping the merged cells intact.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim wsOLrow As Long, wsILrow As Long, wsILcol As Long

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wsO = Sheets("MainSheet")

    wsOLrow = wsO.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
              After:=wsO.Range("A1"), _
              Lookat:=xlPart, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
              MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

    For Each wsI In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If wsI.Name <> wsO.Name Then
            With wsI
                wsILrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

                wsILcol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column

                .Range(Split(Cells(, wsILcol).Address, "$")(1) & "1:" & _
                Split(Cells(, wsILcol).Address, "$")(1) & _
                wsILrow).Copy .Range(Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & "1:" & _
                Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & wsILrow)

                .Activate

                With .Range(Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & "1:" & _
                Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & wsILrow)
                    .UnMerge

                    .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
                End With

                wsILrow = .Range(Split(Cells(, wsILcol).Address, "$")(1) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

                With .Range(Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & "1:" & _
                Split(Cells(, wsILcol + 1).Address, "$")(1) & wsILrow)
                    .Copy

                    wsO.Cells(wsOLrow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, _
                    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

                    .Delete
                End With

                wsOLrow = wsOLrow + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done"
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: The above code is not properly working, its not merging the cells and its displaying the data of only 1 sheet

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball broke :) Can you elaborate more on what is not working?

Comment: my sheet names are 301_CBCompanySync_SAP_to_HHT, 302_CBCustomer_SAP_to_HHT and I want to get the last column values to mainsheet, The merged cells are R2:R25, R26:R49, ...R146:R169 in each sheet

Comment: Sorry, you will have to do slightly better than that. For example. 1) What is the error message that you are getting i.e if you are getting one. 2) If you are not getting any error message then What output were you expecting and what did it actually give :) 3) A sample file of your workbook could help a faster resolution. If you want you can upload the file in wikisend.com and share the link here :)

Comment: http://wikisend.com/download/921844/sample.xlsm, I have attached sample data in here

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed your comment. Looking at your file now.

Comment: when I run this code it says : "Run-time error 91 : Object Variable or With block variable not set"

Comment: Getting error in the following line wsOLrow = wsO.Cells.Find(What:="*", _After:=wsO.Range("A1"), _
              Lookat:=xlPart, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
              SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
              MatchCase:=False).Row + 1

Comment: ah. Seems like you mainsheet is absolutely blank? It doesn't even have headers?

Comment: Yes, the mainsheet is completely blank

Comment: If you plan to keep it blank then use this code instead `wsOLrow = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlup).Row + 1`

Comment: Also if you are 100% sure that it will remain blank then you can also use `wsOLrow = 1`

Comment: The code is perfect now, I attached a sample sheet above with no formulae but the sheet I am using has formula "=MAX(L2:L25)" in column R inside the cell 1 and so on and I doubt its reflecting in the MainSheet as #REF!,

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10529/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-user1292831)